# Help identifying a varistor from a fluorescent light tube ballast

Tags: identification, varistor

I am trying to identify the blown varistor from my fluorescent light tube when I was trying to fix it.

I have never seen a manufacturer marking logo on it with a "W" and a cross in the middle. Not sure what the "P050" means but I think "250" could be the voltage tolerance.

It'll be a great help if somebody knows what the specifications are.

- I found the part for the Dark Red capacitor to replace it.
- The diameter across the varistor is about 7.5mm in diameter.
- The varistor is across the input supply.
- I'm not quite sure for the voltage rating of the ballast probably 220V...? I'm in a European country.

[image: photo showing unknown device]

Comment: I don't think you're going to get very good cost effect repairing old ballasts.  They're so common you should be able to find a replacement cheaper than the sum of the parts.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that. Just a bit curious what's the specs for that part is as didn't see that manufacturer logo before.

Comment: @RichardTan - Thanks. Those were not the answers I expected :-( 7mm is another standard varistor size, so it seems that it's not a 5mm device. Also 250V would be an unusual rating for a varistor across a 220V supply (look at the allowed voltage range on European mains supply voltages and you'll see why). I recommend you check the actual rating on the ballast's label etc, if you're not sure || I will edit the question for you, to add those details, and then remove the previous comments to remove duplication. Those extra details might help someone else.

Comment: @SamGibson - Thanks a lot for adding the details in the post! Yeah, I was trying to find the datasheet from the marking, unfortunately I can't find the manufacturer with that logo. Hope someone who knows about the manufacturer logo cross by.

Comment: Best guess is 50 J and 250 V rating. Try to figure out which company that logo belongs to. That capacitor next to it does not look happy.

Comment: @winny P050 could be the series relate to certain Resistace, holding current & Trip Current. That cap next to it need to buy from China supplier. Not many similar cap could be found around EU

Comment: Dip type capacitors are uncommon here yes, but you can substitute it with something of the same rating and type, but in boxed shape.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's not a varistor even though it looks like one. It was actually the PPTC polyswitch, as when I carried out the continuity test on a good ballast, it gave a beep and the resistance measure without the PCB is around 1 Ohm which is unusual for a varistor. When I connect it to the Power supply, it begin to trip around 0.1A and heating up, once it cools down, it able to work again. So, it is a resettable fuse.

http://www.jdtfuse.com/product/product110_en.html

Found the similar specs on the link, so I think it should be ok.